# Three self-canceling financial transactions for a single recurring contribution?

Tags: accounting, financial-accounts

For recurring contributions, I am getting unusual results in the `civicrm_financial_trxn` table. Three very similar entries are created for each contribution, two of which cancel one another out.

Am I failing to grasp something about double-entry accounting, or are two of these records simply unnecessary?

Or perhaps my financial types are configured to do weird things. Perhaps there *should* be three entries, but at least one account code other than 1150 and 455-11 should be in play. If this is the case, how do I go about identifying the culprit financial account?

Below is a screenshot from the Bookkeeping Transactions Report:

[image: Bookkeeping Transactions Report]

Some notes:

- It's probably not sensitive, but I've changed the transaction number out of an abundance of caution. Note that the original number was the same for all three rows.
- Note that the first and second rows cancel one another out (the amount in the second row is negative).
- Note that the payment method is blank for the third row.

Below is a screenshot of the `civicrm_entity_financial_trxn` entities that feed into the report:

[image: Database view]

Possibly of note:

- There is a four-second delay between the first record and the other two.

**System Details:**
CiviCRM verion: 4.7.29
CMS: Drupal... ahem... 6
Payment processor: Authorize.net

Answer (score 2):

Likely due to [this issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19940?filter=-2).
Looks like there is a PR to correct this with a milestone of 5.4.0, so I guess this problem persists in the current 5.2.1 release.